# How to close network extension when app exit on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Startup a network extension form app, and i want close the network extension when app exit.

method `- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application;` will not call when app is inactive(which means app may be closed by swipe it in recent app list).

Answer (score 3):

Try using the **Manager**'s removeFromPreferences functions, it depends on which provider you use.

**Objective-C**

```
[NEAppProxyProviderManager.sharedManager removeFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"NEAppProxyProviderManager removeFromPreferences error: %@", error);
        }
    }];
[NETunnelProviderManager.sharedManager removeFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"NETunnelProviderManager removeFromPreferences error: %@", error);
        }
    }];
[NEFilterManager.sharedManager removeFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"NEFilterManager removeFromPreferences error: %@", error);
        }
    }];
```

**Swift**

```
NEAppProxyProviderManager.shared().removeFromPreferences { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("NEAppProxyProviderManager removeFromPreferences error: \(error)")
        }
    }
NETunnelProviderManager.shared().removeFromPreferences { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("NETunnelProviderManager removeFromPreferences error: \(error)")
        }
    }
NEFilterManager.shared().removeFromPreferences { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("NEFilterManager removeFromPreferences error: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: As per Apple documentation loadFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler should be called after removing preferences https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nevpnmanager/1406202-removefrompreferenceswithcomplet

Comment: Thanks for highlighting how to use loading from preferences.